# WCF service works in VS but not in build

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf

I have a wcf self hosted service that is meant to be consumed by both computers and android phones. i successfully made the service consumable in both targets but when i built an  exe file (which  is  responsible  for  self  hosting the service)  the service worked great in the pc but it  did not  work on the  mobile app.
here is my service's app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpBinding" maxBufferSize="128000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="128000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00"
          maxBufferSize="6553600" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default" />
    <services>
      <service name="DeltaService.Data">
        <endpoint address="data" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpBinding"
          name="data" contract="DeltaService.IData">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="Rest" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="webBinding" name="restdata" contract="DeltaService.IData">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/delta_api/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Rest">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment
      aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>


  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

and here is the code that launches the service:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Data));
NetHttpBinding netHttpBinding = new NetHttpBinding();
netHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 128 * 1000000; //128Mb
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IData), netHttpBinding, url);
erviceHost.Open();
```

Comment: What does the HTTP activity look like between your mobile device and the server?

Comment: Can other computers on the same network access the service? How the mobile device connected to the computer (or to the same network)? What does your network look like?

Comment: cors? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/08/31/wcf-cors-support-for-self-hosted-wcf-rest-service/

Comment: Yes, Other computers on the same network can access the service, and the mobile device is also connected to the same network.
the android app sends HTTP Json requests to the service and gets JSON responses as well.

Comment: the service works normally when i press run on Visual studio, but when i build an exe file, it doesn't work,  so the problem is either in the app.config file or in the self-hosting app.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a technical description of a problem, its only in your mind. What we need is error messages, log messages, behaviours or anything else that you or someone else could use to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you host the service by using other hosting programs. One thing we must take into consideration is that we needn’t configure the service endpoint and binding information when hosting the service in a hosting program(such as WinForms application).
There is a distinction when hosting in those two ways. When we hosting the service by running on the Visual studio, the system will automatically search for the service configuration, thus the configuration in the Appconfig file will take effect, proper binding generates different kinds of service (restful and soap web service). But the service by using NetHttpBinding will be different from the aforementioned service when hosting the service in other programs.
In a word, I suggest you use below code in the self-hosting program.

```
ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Data));
            sh.Open();
```

It will automatically search for the service configuration in Appconfig file so that the service will be published in proper ways.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured your address to be `localhost`. That address can only be reached from your computer, not from the outside.

When you host your service, pick an address that can be reached from the outside. As I don't know where your device is, I don't know how much "outside" you need. Local network? WAN? Make sure you read a tutorial on that and pick the address or DNS entry you need.